# Is it mandatory that a mysql server have a static IP address? (client is on same local machine)

Tags: mysql, networking

I am using a software - ([Ingress](http://www.fingertec.com/images/w_brochure/Ingress_e.html)) by FingerTec which uses mysql database.

Some setups of this system are only using a single installation - consisting of a **mysql server** and a **client** locally on the same machine.

I have been having issues since I started to use the software when it is installed on a user's laptop/PC. The problem is that frequently when running the mysql server and client, a window pops up asking for the local IP address and port (127.0.0.1 and 3306 by default). To continue using the software, one needs to run IngressDB installer where you need to 'Update Connection' by giving the root user and pass for mysql and then 'Upgrade Database' to refresh the database for any new settings. After this step the software runs fine.

Yesterday I managed to simulate this issue by changing the static IP on my laptop while connected directly to one of their Access Controllers. I had to re-Run Ingress DBinstaller.

Now my question is this:

When using your machine(laptop/pc) it is normally getting IP add, def GW, Subnet etc from a dhcp server therefore there is no guarantee that you will always get the same IP leased unless there is a reservation to the machine's mac address.

As described earlier - when ever there is a change of IP address leased from DHCP, a window pops up showing the loopback address 127.0.0.1 and the mysql port 3306. So it never shows the local IP address (ex. 192.168.1.100). So I was thinking - why is the loopback IP not enough for mysql client/server as this stays the same forever.

Is is normal that software using mysql database server requires a static local IP on the machine hosting it? I am referring only to instances where both mysql server and client reside on the same machine.

I appreciate your thoughts about this and maybe any other way I can get around this apart from making an IP address reservation in the DHCP server. Setting a static IP address manually on the LAN adapter is no solution for me as this would limit the machine to connect only to a certain network and cannot be used at other places.

Comment: I have never encountered a situation where MySQL has problems with connecting from `localhost`. However, I can see why some software might balk at using `localhost` — if it is supposed to run separate machines, then it might prefer a “real” IP address, which doesn’t help you. Could there be a configuration setting in Ingress to this effect?

Answer (score 1):

If the client is the same local machine as the server, the MYSQL server specifically does not need a static IP because it pretty much already has one: 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'. If the client is not on the same machine as the server, the server would need a static IP.

If the machine is acting as a server for other content, yes, it would need a static IP. If you're doing this at home, chances are that your access point will let you configure it for a static IP.

Comment: "If the client is the same local machine as the server, the MYSQL server specifically does not need a static IP because it pretty much already has one: 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'." - YES   So what I am seeing is that I should have the option to set the client specifically to use 127.0.0.1 and rely on that forever.. I will check today.

Comment: If the host is to be used for other content it doesn't really need a static IP as long as it has some dynamic DNS arrangement.